# Seeker of Slaanesh Threat Card Clarification

Tags: relic

In Relic, this threat card says something along the lines of 'If you win, you may discard 1 corruption card. If you do not, gain 1 corruption card".

I interpreted this as if you win the battle, you have to discard one corruption card. If you choose not to (or if you have no corruption to discard), you must gain 1 corruption card.

Another one of the players claimed that it meant if you lose the battle, you draw 1 corruption card (in addition to losing 1 life).

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but you might not have noticed the `may` keyword. if you MAY do something, its optional. that is, if you win then you dont have to discard a card, but you can if you wish to. `may` is a keyword explained in the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card is not intended to include any extra "loss" effect. In other words, if you lose the battle you still just lose 1 Life like normal without taking any additional effect.

In addition, the statement of "If you do not…" in the "win" effect is in reference to whether or not you discarded a Corruption card from the first effect. If you have no Corruption cards to discard or choose not to discard one, you draw 1 Corruption card.

Comment: I originally posted this question on the FFG forums a while ago and this was the answer that came out after a number of posts